# How are scientific computing workflows faring on Apple's M1 hardware

Tags: scipy, r

The initial wave of reviews for Apple's M1 hardware are out, and there's lots of generic benchmarks and data on workflows on professional programs for creative users, but I haven't seen anyone talking about the experience of using something like the scientific computing ecosystem in Python or R.

Does anyone have direct experience with this? Or seen reviews? How fares the Rosetta 2 emulation in terms of either performance in these application spaces or with compilation of packages that don't come in binaries?

Answer (score 10):

The way I have been measuring whether the eco-system is ready is how things are going with the transition for the [homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager.  They have been carefully documenting the progress of getting things running on [apple silicon via a github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7857).  Beyond @Federico Poloni's point the biggest problem is that GCC itself is not yet working and is the reason why many of the packages on homebrew are not yet working.  Now this does not mean a bunch of stuff does not work but I think is a good "canary in the coal mine".  It may be that something like Clang and [Flang](https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang) will replace the GCC toolchain more completely on apple silicon in the end.

Comment: This is largely the approach i am taking myself, Homebrew is an excellent bellwether for platform support for macOS hardware because they have a significant percentage of the macOS experts within the FOSS community working with them. Hopefully it won’t be long, but part of me also hopes that GCC is _never_ supported on M1 hardware, because that will be enough of a kick in the pants that many of the holdouts in the FOSS community need to get their projects working properly with the LLVM compiler stack.

Comment: As an open source developer for more than sixteen long years now, _your entitlement is showing_. Are you _paying_ some developers to make their projects work with LLVM? If not, _who do you think you are_ to insult people who give you _free work_ as "holdouts"?

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I'm with chx here. It is work to port codes to a new compiler. There's also the fact that GCC is actually an excellent compiler that has served the community very well for more than 30 years now.

Comment: Isn't M1 just ARM? Of course GCC supports ARM.

Comment: @user253751 macOS has slightly different calling convention than GNU/Linux operating systems.

Answer (score 8):

From [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651476), it looks like there is no functional native Fortran compiler yet. If that is really the case, things look bleak. Almost anything that uses linear algebra includes some Fortran code (Lapack), and it has to run *fast*.

Comment: Given that M1s appear to run Intel code in emulation faster than existing Intel Macs, is this really an issue? It's faster, it's just not as *much* faster as a native compiler could achieve.

Comment: @chepner According to which benchmarks? Scientific code has a very specific workload and uses different instructions than office work or videogames.

Comment: Maybe, but until you *observe* your code running slower, there's no problem. The lack of a native Fortran compiler may simply be sub-optimal, rather than a setback, and it may also only be temporary.

Comment: @ch I agree, this is just an educated guess. I am not an expert in compilers, but it seems to me that past practice teaches that machine-specific compiler optimizations and vectorized instructions have a big impact on the performance of code. It would be surprising to me if the picture for the M1 were different. I realize that to answer this question properly we need benchmarks --- which is, ultimately, what OP asked for.

Comment: There is at least one  functional native FORTRAN compiler https://www.nag.com/content/nag-fortran-compiler but it is not open source as noted in the link you gave

Comment: Isn't M1 just ARM? How do they compile FORTRAN for the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @user253751 as far as I understand, Gfortran, of which there is only an experimental release for M1.

Answer (score 5):

Iain Sandoe has been working on porting both gcc and gFortran to this architecture. Based on this, François-Xavier Coudert has created an [experimental gFortran](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases) release for the M1. I provide a few Fortran benchmarks [here](https://github.com/neurolabusc/AppleSiliconForNeuroimaging). Presumably this was used for the [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download) Python release that provides a M1 native numpy. One also suspects this is what leman used to provide native M1 [benchmarks for R](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/data-science-r-and-spss-26-etc-under-rosetta-2-apple-silicon-m1.2269302/?post=29326680#post-29326680). However, it is unclear how that build deals with [R's usage of not-a-number values](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/11/02/will-r-work-on-apple-silicon/). It is clear Tomas Kalibera and Simon Urbanek are working on a robust native R solution, but they have not provided a timeline.

I provide benchmarks for a lot of neuroimaging data on [Github](https://github.com/neurolabusc/AppleSiliconForNeuroimaging). The challenge with scientific computing is that there are a lot of different niches. The nature of neuroimaging data means that pipelines tend to be limited by memory bandwidth, not computational power. This allows the M1 to excel in this domain, but my findings may not generalize to other domains.